# Extract nested string from text column

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, plpgsql, postgresql-9.3

I have following SQL result entries.

```
Result
---------
TW - 5657980 Due Date updated :  to <strong>2017-08-13 10:21:00</strong> by <strong>System</strong> 
TW - 5657980 Priority updated  from <strong> Medium</strong> to <strong>Low</strong> by <strong>System</strong> 
TW - 5657980 Material added: <strong>1000 : Cash in Bank - Operating (Old)/ QTY:2</strong> by <strong>System</strong>#9243  
TW - 5657980 Labor added <strong>Kelsey Franks / 14:00 hours </strong> by <strong>System</strong>#65197
```

Now I am trying to extract a short description from this result and trying to migrate it to the another column in the same table.

```
Expected result
--------------
Due Date Updated
Priority Updated
Material Added
Labor Added
```

Ignore first 13 characters. For most of the cases it ends with 'updated'. Few ends with 'added'. It should be case insensitive.
Is there any way to get the expected result.

Comment: There is not enough information to define your task.

Comment: @Erwin: I want to extract string in sql and want expecting result as mentioned.

Comment: The important information missing: does the "short description" always end with "updated" or "added"? Case sensitive? (And none of these words appear more than once?) Is the leading part we ignore always exactly 13 characters long? Or how else are start and end of the string defined exactly?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, yes ignore first 13 characters. it should be there always.Yes for most of the cases it ends with updated.Few ends with added.It should be case insensitive.

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Solution with [`substring()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL) using a regular expression. It *skips the first 13 characters*, then takes the string up to the first *' updated'* or *' added'*, case-insensitive, with leading blank. Else `NULL`:

```
SELECT substring(result, '(?i)^.{13}(.*? (?:updated|added))')
FROM   tbl;
```

The regexp explained:

`(?i)`  .. [meta-syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-METASYNTAX) to switch to case-insensitive matching
`^` .. start of string
`.{13}`  .. skip the first 13 characters
`()`  .. capturing parenthesis (captures payload)
`.*?`  .. any number of characters ([non-greedy](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-QUANTIFIERS-TABLE))
`(?:)`  .. non-capturing parenthesis
`(?:updated|added)`  .. 2 branches (string ends in 'updated' or 'added')

---

If we cannot rely on 13 leading characters [like you later commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46021144/extract-nested-string-from-text-column/46066340#comment79124732_46066340), we need some other reliable definition instead. Your difficulty seems with hazy requirements more than with the actual implementation.

Say, we are dealing with 1 or more non-digits, followed by 1 or more digits, a space and then the payload as defined above:

```
SELECT substring(result, '(?i)^\D+\d+ (.*? (?:updated|added))') ...
```

`\d` .. class shorthand for digits
`\D`  ..  non-digits, the opposite of `\d`

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is it possible to find 13 characters length? I found that if its 12 or 11 characters then gives the wrong result.

Comment: it will be good if we get dynamic characters length.Sometimes its 10 ,11,12 or 13.

Comment: @PranavUnde: All possible, you just have to give complete information *in the question*. What defines the start of the string if not position 14? The first non-digit after the first sequence of digits and a blank? I added another solution based on my educated guess.

Comment: @PranavUnde: give some more Example. Or those for which this code fails